# nginx reverse proxy all domains

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

i'm trying to reverse proxy any requested domain, my code works for specific domains only, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        rewrite_log on;
        proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    }
}
```

this didn't work when **http://localhost:80/www.example.com** requested.

```
    location ~ ^/(.*)/ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$1;
    }
```

nor this one

```
 location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**this actually works**, i didn't realize that because **HTTPS websites doesn't work** on it.

since HTTPS is the standard nowadays on almost any website, this may not worth it for everyone.

```
server {
     listen  80;
     resolver  8.8.8.8;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://$http_host;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

 }
```

**i couldn't** find a solution for the **HTTPS** problem, it would be great to have that.